# Is there a default estimation window in the "eventstudies" package in R?

Tags: r

Can someone tell me how to set the estimation window within this package? For instance, trying for different dates in the `StockPriceReturns` function and `OtherReturns` function seems to give the same results.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think the reason you didn't get any answers to your question is because you did not show any details of your own research, or present a specific problem. This was just a general inquiry into an R package that you could easily research yourself.

Comment: If you reframe your question into an actual problem that you're experiencing, with reproducible code / data, you should get more help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask